# Scaling an icon tabBar loaded with require

Tags: react-native

I want to scale an icon tab loaded with require, I test this code below but that doesn't work, the icon doesn't scale.

```
let img = require('../img/logo_lesson.png');
img.scale = 10;

return(
   <TabBarIOS>
       <TabBarIOS.Item title="React Native"  icon={img}  selected={true}>
```

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is slightly incorrect, img should just contain the image data, not the scale, to scale an icon add it to the icon JSON in the TabBarIOS.Item object like so:

```js
<TabBarIOS.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'thisTab'}
    icon={{uri: 'thisTab', scale: ScaleHere}}
    title='tab'
    onPress={() => {
        this.setState({selectedTab: 'thisTab'});
    }}>


</TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Additionally, you will usually want to multiply your scale by PixelRatio.get() as just hardcoding it to 10 will generally scale incorrectly on different pixel density devices.